# Error while writing into an existing XML file

Tags: vb.net, xmldocument

I am creating an application where I am reading an xml,Adding some nodes and then saving it.

While saving I am getting following error:

> "The process cannot access the file 'C:\p401573\myxml.xml' because it
>   is being used by another process."

My code is as follows:

```
Dim xmldoc As New XmlDocument
xmldoc.Load("C:\p401573\myxml.xml")
Dim nlist As XmlNodeList = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("UserSettings")
Dim elem As XmlElement = xmldoc.CreateElement("", "User", "")
elem.SetAttribute("Name", txtName.Text)
elem.SetAttribute("Rights", "N")
nlist.Item(0).AppendChild(elem)
xmldoc.Save("C:\p401573\myxml.xml")
```

On last line of code when I am saving XML document back to the file above error comes. Sometimes this piece of code is working

myxml.xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UserSettings>
    <User Name="vijavaib" SSOId="45699795" group="New Business" Rights="" />
    <User Name="girinity" SSOId="757888" group="PHS" Rights="" />
    <User Name="bandalpa" SSOId="64567788" group="LICENSING" Rights="" />
    <User Name="hjdhjj" SSOId="658885858" group="PHS" Rights="" />
    <User Name="vvv" SSOId="3165667" group="PHS" Rights="" />
    <User Name="cxvbbb" SSOId="5614367" group="PHS" Rights="" />
    <User Name="cxvbbb" SSOId="5614367" group="LICENSING" Rights="" />
    <User Name="cxvbbb" SSOId="5614367" group="LTCNB" Rights="" />
    <User Name="" SSOId="" group="ALL" Rights="" />
    <User Name="gvbfgfd" SSOId="423556767" group="New Business" Rights="N" />
    <User Name="tgytyry" SSOId="654657676" group="New Business" Rights="N" />
    <User Name="yuuyuut" SSOId="546546757" group="New Business" Rights="N" />
    <User Name="fhgffgjfj" SSOId="576575565" group="New Business" Rights="N" />
    <User Name="hjhjghdj67658" SSOId="654776787" group="New Business" Rights="N" />
    <User Name="hyjhjhgj" SSOId="677887789" group="New Business" Rights="N" />
    <User Name="ttioioiuo" SSOId="787589980" group="ALL" Rights="N" />
 </UserSettings>
```

But sometimes it give error.

Comment: What kind of application is this? Is there *any* chance of another process, a parallel process of any kind touching that file at the same time?

Comment: The error message doesn't make sense in the context of your code. Please show the code that deals with the `C:\p401573\myxml.xml` file.

Comment: I have updated the question please check ,no other process is running only single application is running.Its an winform application.

Comment: Sounds like threading issues. Where is the code in question called? Is it on a UI action?